# How can I get x amount of Data Samples from a List that could contain any amount of records?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a List object that could have any number of elements, from 1 to 1 million (or more).  I am using data in the list to build a graph, and instead of plotting all of the values from the list, I would like to get a small sampling of the data.

The Code:

```
class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeVal1 { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeVal2 { get; set; }
}

List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
```

For example, I would like to return a new List with 100 sampled items (unless of course, there wasn't 100 items in the original list).  My problem is trying to figure out how to 'sample' the data since I will never know if advance how many records are in the list.

Any pointers?

Comment: Why not just get items 0, N where N is any number not greater than the list size?

Comment: You want [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is with a percentage. Imagine that there are 1 million items in the list and you want to collect 100 of them at random, while retaining the order. So what you want is one item in 10,000.

Move sequentially through the list, each time picking a random number from 0 to 10,000. If the number selected is 0, you take that item. So:

```
List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
// list is somehow populated with items

var range = (int)((double)testList.Count/100);
var rnd = new Random();
var selectedItems = new List<Test>();
for (var i = 0; i < testList.Count; ++i)
{
    if (rnd.Next(range) == 0)
    {
        selectedItems.Add(testList[i]);
    }
}
```

*On average*, that will give you 100 items. It might give you slightly more or slightly fewer. If you don't need exactly 100 items, it's probably the easiest way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

With *samples* you mean the count or the size of the sub-list?

You can use `GroupBy` with the remainder operator `%` if you want the former:

```
var subLists = list
    .Select((element, index) => new{ element, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index % 100)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.element).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

This gives you 100 lists. If you want lists with the size 100 replace `%` with `/`.

**Edit:** from your comment:

"I need, regardless of the size of the original list, one new list with only 100 items from the original. Not random items either from the original. The order of the original list would be important on the outcome. "

Then you only need Take:

```
var sample = list.Take(100).ToList();
```

Comment: I need, regardless of the size of the original list, one new list with only 100 items from the original. Not random items either from the original. The order of the original list would be important on the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Test> samples = new List<Test>();
int i = 0;

foreach(var test in testList)
{
    if(i % 100 == 0)
    {
        samples.add(test);
    }
    i++
}
```

This adds every 100th Test in the list to the list samples.

Comment: I think you've got things mixed up - given a list of 1,000,000 values, this produces a sample of size 10,000. Reservoir sampling is what's the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a huge stream data without the specific size and you want to do sampling on it, I strongly recommend [the reservoir sampling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

We can see from the Wikipedia that this algorithm is easy to implement:

```
array R[k];    // result
integer i, j;

// fill the reservoir array
for each i in 1 to k do
    R[i] := S[i]
done;

// replace elements with gradually decreasing probability
for each i in k+1 to length(S) do
    j := random(1, i);   // important: inclusive range
    if j <= k then
        R[j] := S[i]
    fi
done
```

The intuition is:

We read the item from the stream one by one, and when data size

1. within the sample size, we get all data into our sample;
2. exceeding the sample size, we use this new item to randomly replace a item already in the sample, or drop it (based on the random number).

In this way, we can keep the possibility of each item in the final sample remaining the same, making the sampling a fair sample.

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct answer. Just to append though, the OP mentions in a different comment that she needs the sample to preserve order. In that case, she can track the indices of the times in the set and sort them at the end.